# How to download file from httpServlet with Jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, post

In my application, a json object is created on client side. This object is posted to a HttpServlet which creates a pdf file based on the POST data.

The file is send back to the user. The succes function is called, and stream data is logged. I want however, that the file is downloaded.

How to achieve this?

My clientside code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// when the print button is clicked
$('#exportButton').click(function() {

    var tableIdx = performanceDetailTableController.getTableIdx();

    var allData = {
        "shipTable1":{
            "rows":[
                {  "latitude":"12323","longitude":"213213"},
                {  "latitude":"213213","longitude":"543543"}
            ]},
        "shipTable2":{
            "rows":[
                {  "latitude":"12323", "longitude":"213213"},
                {  "latitude":"213213","longitude":"543543"}
            ]}
        }

    var postData = JSON.stringify(allData);

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'pdfServlet',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : postData,
                    async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            alert("got some data");
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

});

And the servlet creating the file:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // get the json content
    StringBuffer jsonContent = getPostedContent(request);

    log.info(jsonContent.toString());

    // convert json to pojo's
    Tables tables = getTablesFromString(jsonContent);

    // create a xml stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream xml = new XmlConverter().getXMLSource(tables);

    // put the xml on the request
    request = setXmlOnRequest(request, xml);

    // create pdf data of the pdf-able xml content
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdf = new PdfHandler().createPdfDataStream(request);

    // response = createResponseheaders(response, request);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(pdf.size());
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.getOutputStream().write(pdf.toByteArray());

    //close the streams
    pdf.close();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

The ouput in the log:

```
%PDF-1.4
%
4 0 obj
<<
/Producer (Apache FOP Version SVN branches/fop-0_95)
/CreationDate (D:20130725162007+02'00')
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
  /N 3
  /Length 11 0 R
  /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xwTSϽ7PhRHH.*1  J
```

**MY SOLUTION: **

see http://www.particletree.com/notebook/ajax-file-download-or-not/ for a pointer

I created a form with one hidden field:

```
        <button id="exportButton">export</button>
    <form id="exportForm" method="post" action="pdfServlet">
        <input type="hidden" value="empty" id="pdf_data" name="pdf_data" />
    </form>
```

than i changed my jquery post data controller to:

```
    $('#exportButton').click(function() {

    var tableIdx = performanceDetailTableController.getTableIdx();

        var allData = {
        "shipTable1":{
            "rows":[
                {  "latitude":"12323","longitude":"213213"},
                {  "latitude":"213213","longitude":"543543"}
            ]},
        "shipTable2":{
            "rows":[
                {  "latitude":"12323", "longitude":"213213"},
                {  "latitude":"213213","longitude":"543543"}
            ]}
        } 



    var postData = JSON.stringify(allData);

    // put the data on the hidden form field in the export form
    $('#pdf_data').val(postData);

    // and submit the form
    $('#exportForm').submit();

});
```

so now when i click the export button, the hidden field in the form gets the data to post and the data is posted as www-form encoded.

This way the servlet can handle the request and the the file is downloaded to the client.

Comment: You cannot force a file download with ajax.

Comment: Ajax responses are not allowed to download files .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't download files with ajax. JavaScript has for obvious security reasons no facilities to trigger a *Save As* dialogue with arbitrarily retrieved/generated content in JavaScript context. The world wide web would have looked very different if that was possible.

If you insist in using JS/jQuery for that, you need to send a synchronus GET request instead. You can do that with `window.location` (you only need to rename `doPost()` to `doGet()`).

```
window.location = 'pdfServlet?param1=value1&param2=value2';
```

Alternatively, just throw away all that unnecessary JS/jQuery and just use plain HTML `<form action="pdfServlet" method="post">` with `<input type="submit">`. Additional bonus is that it works in browsers with JS disabled.

If your sole reason to grab ajax is actually a naive attempt to avoid the page being refreshed, then I can tell you that this really won't happen if the response has a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header. So that part is already safe.

Comment: His request is a POST. Gonna have to play around with that.

Comment: so basically i would have the user post its content, create a pdf file with that, write it to disk on the server and provide the user with a link from which he can download the file?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i dont think using a form is possible is this situation, but'll check it out.

Comment: @Paul: nonsense. A file download (a `Content-Disposition:attachment` response) doesn't cause a page refresh.

Comment: jorrebor, just write PDF to response. Exactly as you have now. Your servlet is completely fine. Your only problem is how you invoke it. It should be done synchronously, not asynchronously.

Comment: I want to rectify the "Your servlet is completely fine" statement in my previous comment. It actually isn't. That whole read/write loop is completely unnecessary if your input is already fully in memory in flavor of a `byte[]`. Just do `response.getOutputStream().write(pdf.toByteArray());`. Note that it'd be more efficient if `PdfHandler` wrote to `response.getOutputStream()` immediately instead of creating an in-memory `byte[]`. But this all is unrelated to the actual functionality of sending a file download.